# Copy file from container to host using Dockerfile or Docker-compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

Good afternoon

I'm a new user of Docker and I have a question please:

I created a container named "container_worker" which running a Python script to create some data.
The data created is stored in the container in a file named "data".

I want to copy this "data" file to my host to be able to use it for another purpose.
I saw it's possible to do it with the "docker cp" command but I want to do it directly in my Dockerfile or my Docker-compose file.

Here are my files:

Dockerfile:

```
FROM archlinux

RUN pacman-db-upgrade \
&& pacman -Syyu --noconfirm \
&& pacman -S python --noconfirm \
&& pacman -S python-pip --noconfirm \
&& pip install requests

COPY /worker/script.py .

CMD python3 vmtracer.py >> data
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3"
services:
  worker:
    image: image_worker
    container_name: container_worker
    build:
      dockerfile: ./worker/Dockerfile
```

Thank you very much.

Comment: A Docker container has an isolated filesystem, and can't usually read or write files from the host.  Would it make more sense to run this program in a Python virtual environment, without Docker?

Comment: Hello, thank you for the advice. But I want to use Docker. I found a way with volumes between host and container. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can bind/mount volume from your local machine to container and put the output to that shared location. 
Use command docker volume create my-vol , to create volume. 
Use command docker volume ls ,to list your volumes. 
Use parameter volumes: {your-volume-name} in docker-compose file to use the created volume.

Refer the link for more : https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/